# Search directory greather than n size

Tags: powershell, directory, size

Is there any PowerShell command that can iterate through a specific path in order to find directories bigger than n size?
I know I can find **files** bigger than n size, but I need to verify **directory** size, because there are situations where in a folder there are 1000 files, each one of 1 MB, so the total of the directory is 1 GB.
And this was happening under C:\windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell cmdlets don't accumulate the sizes of nested items in a directory, but you can use the [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx) COM object for this:

```
$threshold = 1GB

$fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\root\folder' -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {
    $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size -gt $threshold
}
```

The `-Directory` parameter was introduced with PowerShell v3. If you need this to work on PowerShell v2 you need to select directories with a `Where-Object` filter.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\root\folder' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size -gt $threshold
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little bit strange. Could you tell me what measure unit does it use? cause I've tested it...and for the $threshold = 10000000 it shows me even directories that are 25 MB total.

Comment: The unit is bytes, so your result is rather unsurprising since 10,000,000 bytes are just 10MB, hence less than 25MB. The `Size` property should show the same value you see in parentheses when you open the properties dialog of a folder. You can use PowerShell's [byte conversion constants](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx) to make the threshold value more readable (e.g. `$threshold = 1GB`).

Comment: It works only for powershell 3 or greater. seems on 2 it can't include -Directory argument. Is it possible to make some change in order to work on powershell v2 also? Thanks!

Comment: See updated answer. If you're restricted to PowerShell v2 you should mention that in your question, since PowerShell v3 was released five years ago and introduced important new features.